# Eclipse - Add Completion For /* Comment

Tags: eclipse, completion

How can I add completion support for the `/* */` comment in eclipse?
So that it automatically appends `*/` when I type `/*`.

Comment: Type it and hit enter, it should add it.

Comment: Do you want to have a one-line block comment?

Comment: Yes, I would like to have a one-line comment.